# Angular 4 Dynamic Forms: Edit Dropdown NOT Working

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, dropdown, renderer

I am creating an Angular 4 dynamic multi step form. The last step of the form shows the user all the values they have entered and gives them a chance to edit. When a user clicks "edit" it will take them back to that particular question.

Edit works with inputs and checkboxes, but does not work with dropdowns. It will focus on that element, but does not show the value the user originally selected.

I have include an [example](https://ng-run.com/edit/AYHRywSuo9Fh7DpFU7hj).

Is there something I have to do differently with dropdowns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using `this.renderer2.selectRootElement` method because it clears content of your selected element:

```typescript
selectRootElement(selectorOrNode: string|any): any {
    let el: any = typeof selectorOrNode === 'string' ? 
            document.querySelector(selectorOrNode) :
            selectorOrNode;
    if (!el) {
      throw new Error(`The selector "${selectorOrNode}" did not match any elements`);
    }
    el.textContent = ''; <==================== this code
    return el;
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.ts#L137-L145

One option to handle autofocus is passing `focusedKey` to dynamic form:

```html
<dynamic-control [input]="control" [form]="form" [focusedKey]="focusedKey">
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then you can create autofocus directive like:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[autofocus]'
})
export class AutofocusDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @Input() set autofocus(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.el.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

and use it instead of `id` and `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
<select [autofocus]="focusedKey === input.key"
```

**[Fixed Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/WZJ0qD28smEpRGGUdntd?open=app%2Fdynamic-form%2Fdynamic-form.component.html&layout=1)**

Comment: Any reason why `this.renderer2.selectRootElement` is clearing out the content of the dropdown only? Because it doesn't do that for textboxes. Odd.

Comment: It doesn't do the same with checkboxes because checkboxes don't have content. They're void elements. `checkbox.textContent = ''` has no effect